# JQuery equivalent of MooTools bind(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, mootools-events

I'm trying to rewrite a Mootools tooltip class in JQuery using this [class plugin](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/jQuery.Class.html#&who=jQuery.Class). When my class is instantiated I'm attaching an event listener to a target link which will fade out the tooltip.

In event callbacks JQuery assigns the keyword "this" to the target of the event, so to keep a reference to the properties of the class I'm using `apply()` to set "this" to mean the class instance. This is apparently the counterpart in JQuery of Mootools' handy `bind()` function.

Unfortunately when I use `apply()` I lose the callback's event parameter. For example, in this bit I get an "e is undefined" error on the second line.

```
this.target.bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tip = this.opts.tip;
    tip.fadeOut(500, function(){
        tip.bind('click', function(){
            showing = false;
        })
    });
}.apply(this))
```

Am I missing a trick here? Does anybody know a way around this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TBH, the `mootools` `.bind` as you call it is just `Function.bind` in ES5 - and is available natively in browsers that support the js 1.8.5 + spec. MooTools just enhances browsers that don't have it yet but lets the native implementation remain on the prototype - if available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

You can easily implement that as a a `Function.prototype.bind` decorator if not available natively and use it as the example above says:

```
// Function.prototype.bind polyfill
if ( !Function.prototype.bind ) {

  Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {
    if(typeof this !== 'function') // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');

    var slice = [].slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        self = this, 
        nop = function () {}, 
        bound = function () {
          return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} ), 
                              args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );    
        };

    bound.prototype = this.prototype;

    return bound;
  };
}
```

As you can see, it's a little more involved than a simple `.apply` / `.call`

One thing to consider is, if you NEED to use bind or if you can save a reference instead.

eg.

```
var self = this;
this.target.bind("click", function(e) {
    var tip = self.opts.tip;
});
```

this has a smaller footprint than the function binding anyway. it also affords you a correct reference to `this` as the trigger element (`event.target === this`). you will find this pattern far more often in mootools-core than the bind one - though bind is often needed when you want to assign events to class methods, eg:

```
this.element.addEvents({
    click: this.showTip.bind(this),
    mouseleave: this.hideTip.bind(this)
});
```

In this case, saving a reference won't work though you can rewrite it as

```
var self = this;
this.element.addEvents({
    click: function(e) {
        self.showTip(e);
    }
});
```

A jQuery particular implementation is `proxy` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/

Comment: Dimitar you're a walking encyclopaedia of JS! Thanks for the detailed explanation. In this situation your suggestion of a reference seems to be the best, so I'd do like:

` var self = this;
 this.target.bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  self.toggleTip();
 })`

in my init method, where toggleTip() is a separate click callback.

Great advice, thanks!

Comment: @Dimitar: Works great indeed. thnx. (at)all: Notice that this technique  of functional programming is called currying (http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/). jQuery has similar prototype extension of the method name 'bind' which maybe somewhat confusing because it is used for events handling and declared on non-functions. In jQuery there is also a use of context in $.ajax for similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

All events, that are made on some element (e.g. 'click' is one of them) should have a target property pointing to that element

```
var $this = $(e.target); // $this will be the clicked element
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYVfH/)

Comment: Thanks mkilmanas - that's the property I was hoping to use. Unfortunately when I added apply() to the end of my function I lost access to it.